# Highlight a column value based off another column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function like this:

```
def highlight_otls(df):
    return ['background-color: yellow']
```

And a DataFrame like this:

```
price   outlier 
1.99       F,C
1.49       L,C
1.99         F
1.39         N
```

What I want to do is highlight a certain column in my df based off of this condition of another column:

```
data['outlier'].str.split(',').str.len() >= 2
```

So if the column values df['outlier'] >= 2, I want to highlight the corresponding column df['price']. (So the first 2 prices should be highlighted in my dataframe above).

I attempted to do this by doing the following which gives me an error:

```
data['price'].apply(lambda x: highlight_otls(x) if (x['outlier'].str.split(',').str.len()) >= 2, axis=1)
```

Any idea on how to do this the proper way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Styler.apply`. (To output to `xlsx` format, use [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Export-to-Excel) function.)

Suppose one's dataset is

```
other   price   outlier
0   X   1.99    F,C
1   X   1.49    L,C
2   X   1.99    F
3   X   1.39    N

def hightlight_price(row):
    ret = ["" for _ in row.index]
    if len(row.outlier.split(",")) >= 2:
        ret[row.index.get_loc("price")] = "background-color: yellow"
    return ret
       
df.style.\
    apply(hightlight_price, axis=1).\
    to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html), "`DataFrame.style` attribute is a property that returns a Styler object."

We pass our styling function, `hightlight_price`, into `Styler.apply` and demand a row-wise nature of the function with `axis=1`. (Recall that we want to color the `price` cell in each row based on the `outlier` information *in the same row*.)

Our function `hightlight_price` will generate the visual styling ***for each row***. For each row `row`, we first generate styling for `other`, `price`, and `outlier` column to be `["", "", ""]`. We can obtain the right index to modify only the `price` part in the list with `row.index.get_loc("price")` as in

```
ret[row.index.get_loc("price")] = "background-color: yellow"
# ret becomes ["", "background-color: yellow", ""]
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'm getting the error: 'AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index 0')' although the 'outlier' column is a str with some NaN values, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: can you also specify for the highlighting format to apply to the 'price' column? in my actual dataframe, there are other columns I do not want highlighted. Thanks!

Comment: @Hana For your first problem, I think that is because you have some missing data like `NaN` in the `outlier` column. Can you check it for me with `df.outlier.isna().any()`?

Comment: @Hana for you second problem, please see the update.

Comment: @Hana if your first problem is caused by something like `NaN`, use `df.outlier.fillna("", inplace=True)` to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

**Key points**

1. You need to access values in the multiple columns for your `lambda` function, so apply to the whole dataframe instead of the price column only.
2. The above also solves the issue that apply for a series has no `axis` argument.
3. Add `else x` to fix the syntax error in the conditional logic for your `lambda`
4. When you index `x` in the `lambda` it is a value, no longer a series, so kill the `str` attribute calls and just call `len` on it.

So try:

```
data.apply(lambda x: highlight_otls(x) if len(x['outlier'].split(',')) >= 2 else x, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
0    [background-color: yellow]
1    [background-color: yellow]
2                  [None, None]
3                  [None, None]
dtype: object
```

One way to deal with null outlier values as per your comment is to refactor the highlighting conditional logic into the `highlight_otls` function:

```
def highlight_otls(x):                                                            
     if len(x['outlier'].split(',')) >= 2:
         return ['background-color: yellow']
     else:
         return x

data.apply(lambda x: highlight_otls(x) if pd.notnull(x['outlier']) else x, axis=1)
```

By the way, you may want to return something like `['background-color: white']` instead of `x` when you don't want to apply highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! How can I add pd.notnull() to x['outlier']? There are some instances where there are no outliers in my full dataframe, so I'm getting this error - AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: So actually when I output my the excel file with this code, I don't see any yellow highlighted fields, any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use custom function for return `styled DataFrame` by condition, last [export Excel file](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Export-to-Excel):

```
def highlight_otls(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c2 = '' 

    mask = x['outlier'].str.split(',').str.len() >= 2
    df1 =  pd.DataFrame(c2, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    #modify values of df1 column by boolean mask
    df1.loc[mask, 'price'] = c1

    #check styled DataFrame
    print (df1)

                          price outlier
    0  background-color: yellow        
    1  background-color: yellow        
    2                                  
    3                               
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight_otls, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Hey this is giving me error: 'TypeError: Function <function highlight_otls at 0x1a274f60d0> must return a DataFrame when passed to `Styler.apply` with axis=None' any idea how to fix it?